# Is the unit object in a closed monoidal category always integral?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, monoidal-categories

I.Bucur and A.Deleanu in their ["Introduction to the theory of categories and functors"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007Q47LLO) define *integral object* in a category ${\mathcal C}$ as  an arbitrary object $I$ that satisfies the following two conditions:

1) for any object $X$ there is a morphism $i:I\to X$, and

2) for any pair of parallel morphisms $u,v:X\to Y$ the condition $u\ne v$ implies the existense of a morphism $i:I\to X$ such that 
$$
u\circ i\ne v\circ i.
$$

Let now ${\mathcal C}$ be an arbitrary [closed monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category). My question:

> Is the unit object $I$ in ${\mathcal C}$ always integral?

In the examples that I know this is true, but apparently I don't see some  tricks, I can't prove this for arbitrary category ${\mathcal C}$.

I would appreciate very much if somebody could clarify this to me.

Comment: I haven't heard the term "integral object" before. Your second condition corresponds to (the ugly, ugly contrapositive of) the notion of a [separating object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator#definitions). I'd probably describe $I$ as a [weakly initial](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weakly+initial+object), separating object.

Comment: @DerekElkins for me this word sounds strange as well. But Bucur and Deleanu use it (at page 31). I did not know that this is called a separating object, I'll have in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, taking the category of sets with the Cartesian product, the unit object (a singleton) is not integral since it has no morphism to the empty set.  More generally, if you take the category of sheaves (of sets, or of abelian groups if you want an abelian category say) on some site, both properties (1) and (2) will typically fail since a sheaf can have no global sections or not be generated by global sections.  For instance, if you take the category of sheaves of sets on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $X$ be the sheaf given by $X(U)=\{*\}$ if $U\subseteq(0,1)$ and $X(U)=\emptyset$ otherwise, the two inclusions $X\to X\coprod X$ are distinct but $X$ has no morphisms from the unit object (which is the constant singleton sheaf).

Comment: Ah, yes. Eric, if we remove the first condition will this be true nevertheless?

Comment: Eric, I am not sure that I understand why the condition (2) fails in the case of sheaves. Could you, please, give a concrete example?

Comment: So "the" category of sheaves is a counterexample to the claim that the "unit object is a separating object in any closed monoidal category"? (I.e. we can't replace the role of the terminal object in the cartesian closed categories $Set$ or $Cat$ with the unit, in terms of "identifying objects by their points", using the unit object of an arbitrary closed monoidal category?) That seems like the conclusion from this answer, but I know very little algebraic geometry so I wanted to check.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: I don't understand what you mean in your parenthetical.  The terminal object *is* the unit of the cartesian monoidal structure (i.e., the one where the monoidal product is the categorical product).  But yes, if you take the category of sheaves of sets on some site with the cartesian monoidal structure then typically the unit object is not a separating object.

Comment: yeah you're right, reading that again that was poorly worded -- you figured out what I meant correctly though