# Multiplication and division by a morphism under the "inner composition" in closed monoidal categories

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, monoidal-categories

Let ${\mathcal C}$ be a symmetric [closed monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category), and let me denote the internal hom-functor by a fraction
$$
(X,Y)\mapsto\frac{Y}{X},
$$
so that we have an isomorphism of functors
$$
\operatorname{Mor}(A\otimes B,C)\cong\operatorname{Mor}\left(A,\frac{C}{B}\right).
$$
As is known, ${\mathcal C}$ is an [enriched category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category+theory) over itself. For each objects $A,B,C$ let me denote by $\bullet_{A,B,C}$ the "inner composition" in ${\mathcal C}$ as in an enriched category, i.e. the morphism 
$$
\bullet_{A,B,C}:\frac{C}{B}\otimes\frac{B}{A}\to\frac{C}{A}
$$
with the corresponding properties.

> I wonder if the following identity always holds
>   $$
> \bullet_{A,C,D}\circ\left(1_{\frac{D}{C}}\otimes\frac{\varphi}{1_A}\right)= 
> \bullet_{A,B,D}\circ\left(\frac{1_D}{\varphi}\otimes1_{\frac{B}{A}}\right)
> $$
>   (for arbitrary objects $A,B,C,D$ and for arbitrary morphism $\varphi:B\to C$).

[image: multiplication and division by a morphism under the inner multiplication]

This is strange, I can prove this only in the case when [the unit $I$ is a separating object in ${\mathcal C}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator#definitions) (what [does not always hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246600/is-the-unit-object-in-a-closed-monoidal-category-always-integral/3246610#3246610)). Is it possible that there is a couterexample?

**Edit:** I asked this now at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335117/multiplication-and-division-by-a-morphism-under-the-inner-composition-in-close).

Comment: Where are you getting this "division" notation?

Comment: @DerekElkins this is my own attempt to shorten the writings. Fraction seems to be a convenient notation for closed monoidal categories: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_space#Category_Ste_of_stereotype_spaces

Comment: @ArnaudD. what do you think?

Comment: The division notation is actually rather popular among allegory theorists and you can even find it in category theory introductions such as Fokkinga's works.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy could you, please, give me a reference to Fokkinga's papers?

Comment: Here's one of my favourites https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf92b.pdf ;; it uses division for colimits ;; see "Categories, Allegories" for the use of division for residuals, which generalise Kan extensions ;-)

Comment: Musa, thank you!